# Amazon S3 GetBucketLocation throws an exception with error code InvalidAccessKeyId when testing bucket's region

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-s3

I configure an `AmazonS3Client` with the correct `AccessKeyId` and `SecretAccessKey`, and also supplying the region to the supposed bucket we will be testing against (if it exists).

Interestingly, this so far happens only when someone supplies a Chinese region (like `cn-north-1`).

When I make the request using `AmazonS3Client.GetBucketLocationAsync`, I get an `AmazonS3Exception` with an error code of `InvalidAccessKeyId`.

If I change the region to something else - for example europe, everything works correctly, even if I don't have such a bucket in that region.

What's going on?

Exception's Message: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`